# Completion block never called in setCollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm updating the layout of a `UICollectionView` by moving a cell.

```
collectionView.moveItem(at: sourceIndex, to: destIndex)

collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(collectionView.collectionViewLayout, animated: true)
{ (done) in
      print("i'm here")
}
```

But the completion block of `setCollectionViewLayout` is never called, while the animation is correctly done.
Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: And I finally found that I don't need setCollectionViewLayout because the moveItem already do the animation...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

BallpointBen is correct - the structure change is not needed.

I believe the reason you do not get the completion block is because you are setting the **New** layout to the **Existing** layout. So, because there is no actual change, there is no "completion".

<s>Whoops... The structure should probably be:</s>

```
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(collectionView.collectionViewLayout, 
        animated: true, completion: {
            (done) in
            print("I'm here")
    })
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what OP wrote

Comment: Isn't the `completion:` needed?